# No "New Folder" button in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

My sibling's laptop is running windows 7 x64.

The torrents folder in Documents doesn't show the New Folder button. ctrl+shift+n doesn't work either.

I tried EVERYTHING here: [Can't create new folder from anywhere in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/76916/cant-create-new-folder-from-anywhere-in-windows-7)

..but nothing worked. As with the OP there, running the .reg file brings an error that says something about not being able to change the registry value while something is using it. I removed one entry at a time in the .reg file until I narrowed down the ones that were causing the problem, which were in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/CLSID. The only different reg value, however, was in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}\InProcServer32, for which the default value was `%SystemRoot%\system32\explorerframe.dll` and the value trying to be set `ExplorerFrame.dll`. I'm on windows 7 32bit and that's the same value I have for the entry, so I doubt that's it.

The only thing I think is slightly off is that there is a user group with a strange name that only has execute and read access, and I can't grant it full control. Every time I try, it acts as if it works, but doesn't change it. I tried booting into safe mode and changing it, but it did the same thing.

It is the folder where utorrent puts any new downloads, so it's possible utorrent did something, though that's never happened to me before.

edit:

I had renamed the folder to something else to avoid the problem, and then went onto my own computer to try to figure out what was wrong (I personally don't like using the touchpad on laptops). While searching, my sibling starting watching a movie. I minimized the movie and saw that the same thing had happened to the folder I renamed. Also changed was the file layout. It showed the different days and the files modified on those days.

So, I was able to fix it by doing:

1. Clicking Organize > Layout > Menu Bar
2. On the menu bar clicking View > Arrange By > Folder

Comment: *"user group with a strange name"*: Please edit your question to include the actual name. This may be an important clue.

Comment: Can you create a folder from the command prompt?

Comment: @RandolphWest, mkdir didn't work.

Comment: if you are administrator, go to properties of the concerned folder and switch to security tab. There, take the ownership of the folder.

Answer (score 2):

First, please use [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) tool to troubleshoot this issue.

If the issue persists, import the following registry key and see if the issue can be resolved.

First, please refer to [this knowledge base (KB) article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Back-up-the-registry) to back up the registry key. After backing up the registry, please follow the steps below to import the registry:

**1.** Click Start, type Notepad in the Search bar and pres ENTER.
**2.** Copy the following commands and then paste them into the open Notepad window.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}]
> @="CLSID_ExecuteFolder"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}\InProcServer32]
> @="ExplorerFrame.dll"
> "ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
> @="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder]
> @="Folder"
> "EditFlags"=hex:d2,03,00,00
> "FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.Size"
> "ThumbnailCutoff"=dword:00000000
> "TileInfo"="prop:System.Title;System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemType"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\DefaultIcon]
> @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,00,00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore]
> "MultiSelectModel"="Document"
> "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000022
> "ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000021
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
> @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\00,65,00,2c,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,\2c,00,25,00,4c,00,00,00
> "DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open]
> "MultiSelectModel"="Document"
> "BrowserFlags"=dword:00000010
> "ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000012
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command]
> @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,00,25,00,4c,00,\00,00
> "DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers{F9DB5320-233E-11D1-9F84-707F02C10627}]
> @="PDF Column Info"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\BriefcaseMenu]
> @="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Offline Files]
> @="{474C98EE-CF3D-41f5-80E3-4AAB0AB04301}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers{BD472F60-27FA-11cf-B8B4-444553540000}]
> @=""
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\BriefcasePage]
> @="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Offline Files]
> @="{7EFA68C6-086B-43e1-A2D2-55A113531240}"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew]
> "Directory"=""
> "IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,\00,00
> "ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30396"
> "MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30317"
> "NonLFNFileSpec"="@shell32.dll,-30319"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config]
> "AllDrives"=""
> "IsFolder"=""
> "NoExtension"=""

**3.** After pasting the above commands, please click File on the menu and click Save.
**4.** Type in NewFolder.reg as the file name, select to save the file on the Desktop. Click Save.
**5.** Go to the Desktop, and double click `NewFolder.reg`. A dialog box will pop-up saying **"Are you sure you want to add the information in fix.reg to the registry?"**. Click `Yes` to confirm.

Just ignore the **"key cannot be written"** error when running the `NewFolder.reg` file if it persist and try to create new folder.

**Note:** Administrative privileges are required to perform the above steps. Please click "Continue" when the User Account Control dialog-box appears.

All information is provided above from [Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/97de8a2a-12f2-4381-a409-a78f4ae551cf).