# Windows Explorer can no longer make new folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

I (actually, a very unfortunate friend of mine)
  can no longer create new folders from the Windows Explorer program.
(It is important to note that `mkdir` and friends still work.)
I have no idea how this came to be, but my friend denies any system-wide changes around the time it started.

How might I go about adding it back in as it would normally be?

(Note also that other context menu options remain—the 'new folder' one simply is not among them.)

Comment: The computer ran out of empty folders to use, and your friend needs to contact the local Microsoft sales outlet to buy and install the *Empty Folders Super-Pack*. Note that `mkdir` creates directories, not folders (it says so by name) and thus is not affected by this issue. (Okay, just kidding.)

Comment: Create a new user account see if it works if not reinstall windows

Comment: read this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180257 and this: http://superuser.com/questions/76916/cant-create-new-folder-from-anywhere-in-windows-7

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This is possibly one of the best things I've ever read on SU XD. On a serious note, can you run a `sfc /scannow` and see if there are any errors corrected?

Comment: @moses No juice—no integrity violations.

Comment: @BenPlont nice links! The [highest-voted answer](http://superuser.com/a/111963/160871) on that one managed to fix the problem, but I'm going to add a caveat as a comment to it for something I had to do (quit `explorer` before install)

Comment: @moses OS/2 2.x actually did it [pretty much that way](http://toastytech.com/guis/os220templates.png): to create a new, empty folder, you used a "folder" *template*. I think [they borrowed the idea from the original Mac OS](http://toastytech.com/guis/mac11deskicons.gif) (note the "Empty Folder") but I can't find an easy confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

He could try going into the `Folder Options` from the `Control Panel` and Restoring all folder options to default. There's nothing in there to indicate that the context menu could be modified in any way, but I guess it's worth a go.