# Option to Create New Folder Disappeared

Tags: windows-7

On my friend's Windows 7 installation, the option to create a new folder is missing. What happened to it, and how can it be brought back?

[image: New Folder option Missing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create new folder from anywhere in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/76916/cant-create-new-folder-from-anywhere-in-windows-7).

Comment: @and31415 It's not a duplicate since my friend could access the New Folder option from other places in Windows 7 but not from the context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should be caused by damaged or incorrect registry key entry. Please check the following registry value:

1. Click Start, type regedit in Search Bar, and then click regedit in the Programs list.
   Note: If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type your password or click Continue.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New\

3. Please check if the value for (Default) is:

   > {D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}

If the issue persists after changing the registry key value, please continue to try the following suggestions:

1. Click Start, type regedit in Search Bar, and then click regedit in the Programs list.
   Note: If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type your password or click Continue.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

   > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder
3. Right click on the Folder key on the left pane, and then select "Export" to backup this registry key.
4. Go to [Skydrive](http://cid-be2a687d297ce921.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Registry%20Keys/folderfix.zip) and download folderfix.zip file.
5. Save the folderfix.zip file on to your Desktop.
6. Right click and extract the folderfix.reg file.
7. Right click on the folderfix.reg file and then click Merge.
8. Click Yes to confirm the modification.

Hope this helps.
Source - [Option to create new folder on desktop is missing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ee6ecdf-5958-4af4-b640-c659ada57bc4/option-to-create-new-folder-on-desktop-is-missing)

> Or you can also use " Ctrl + Shift + N " hotkey to create folder anywhere!

Answer (score 3):

The "folderfix.reg" above worked for my system running Windows 10, so just in case that link ever breaks, here are its exact contents.  Simply copy to a text file, rename to *.reg, and run:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder]
@="Folder"
"EditFlags"=hex:d2,03,00,00
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.Size"
"ThumbnailCutoff"=dword:00000000
"TileInfo"="prop:System.Title;System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemType"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]
@=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore]
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000022
"ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000021

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
  00,65,00,2c,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,\
  2c,00,25,00,4c,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open]
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000010
"ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000012

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
  00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,00,25,00,4c,00,\
  00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\BriefcaseMenu]
@="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{474C98EE-CF3D-41f5-80E3-4AAB0AB04301}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers\{BD472F60-27FA-11cf-B8B4-444553540000}]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\BriefcasePage]
@="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{7EFA68C6-086B-43e1-A2D2-55A113531240}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew]
"Directory"=""
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30396"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30317"
"NonLFNFileSpec"="@shell32.dll,-30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config]
"AllDrives"=""
"IsFolder"=""
"NoExtension"=""
```

Comment: Helped without a restart. Big thanks!